# setting up ckan datastore POST failed

Tags: datastore, ckan

I have installed CKAN on Ubuntu 14.04 from package and now I'm setting up the datastore.

I followed the instructions from here:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/datastore.html.

**When I test it using GET it seems okay**

```
roderico@roderico-VirtualBox:~$ curl -X GET "http://localhost/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata"{"help": "http://192.168.1.3/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search", "success": true, "result": {"include_total": true, "resource_id": "_table_metadata", "fields": [{"type": "int", "id": "_id"}, {"type": "name", "id": "name"}, {"type": "oid", "id": "oid"}, {"type": "name", "id": "alias_of"}], "records_format": "objects", "records": [], "_links": {"start": "/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata", "next": "/api/3/action/datastore_search?offset=100&resource_id=_table_metadata"}, "total": 0}}
```

**but then when I do the POST it fails**

```
roderico@roderico-VirtualBox:~$ curl -X POST http://localhost/api/3/action/datastore_create -H "Authorization: {1478356f-8f8f-4f16-a7c0-8bce46b6bece}" -d '{"resource": {"package_id": "{10aa3af0-a55c-4184-a13b-de8bb8047096}"}, "fields": [ {"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"} ], "records": [ { "a": 1, "b": "xyz"}, {"a": 2, "b": "zzz"} ]}'
```

with this response:

```
{"help": "http://192.168.1.3/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create", "success": false, "error": {"message": "Access denied: <function datastore_create at 0x7f268d98baa0> requires an authenticated user", "__type": "Authorization Error"}}
```

It says Authorization error so I don't know may be I'm using the wrong details. Any idea?

I got the api key from the profile and the package id from the url
http://192.168.1.3/dataset/amigos/resource/10aa3af0-a55c-4184-a13b-de8bb8047096

Comment: Did you set the permissions to datastore? https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/datastore.html#set-permissions

Comment: yes I did this command . rico-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan$ paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini | sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
You are now connected to database "datastore_default" as user "postgres".
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
CREATE VIEW
ALTER VIEW
GRANT
CREATE FUNCTION
ALTER FUNCTION
DO

Comment: However, this command gives me an error, curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol, . curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/datastore_create -H "Authorization: {YOUR-API-KEY}" -d '{"resource": {"package_id": "{PACKAGE-ID}"}, "fields": [ {"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"} ], "records": [ { "a": 1, "b": "xyz"}, {"a": 2, "b": "zzz"} ]}'

Comment: Your `curl` code for the `POST` request shows curly braces (`{}`) around the value of the `Authentication` header. Those shouldn't be there, please try again without them.